# How to make tcsh not insert whitespace in a command that spans multiple lines

Tags: shell-script, quoting, tcsh

Bash does not seem to insert whitespace but tcsh does.

**Tcsh**

```
bash-3.2.25$ tcsh -c 'echo $tcsh; echo A\
> B'
6.14.00
A B
```

**Bash**

```
bash-3.2.25$ bash -c 'echo A\
> B'
AB
```

How can I ask tcsh to not insert a space between A and B?

Comment: Hmm, why is multiple line necessary?

Comment: @warl0ck I wanted to break a long command line to make it short/manageable